# JAVA method calling upon method

Tags: java, jna, rect

I think i confused myself a little bit - anyways, how do i call a method upon another method. Like method().method().method(); ?
I'd like to create a similar method myself for this sample code:

```
public RECT getPositionOfClient() {
    HWND client = User32.INSTANCE.FindWindow("classname", "client");
    RECT rect = new RECT();
    User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowRect(client , rect);
    System.out.println("rect = " + rect);
    return rect;
}
```

Here i'd like to be able call
`getPositionOfClient().getTop(); or getPositionOfClient().getBottom();` 
which is something the JNA RECT class provides (top,bottom, left, right).
How do i do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: method1().method2() is valid if method1 is going to return an Object which can invoke method2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make that possible, you need **fluent** APIs.

Meaning: each of your methods ... has to return some **object**; like:

```
Whatever a() { ... does something ... and 
 return whatEverInstance;
}
```

and then, when all your a()s, and b()s return something, you can write down such code.

And if you "stay" within **the same class**, and each method is just doing a

```
return this;
```

so you keep calling methods on the same object; than that is a somehow acceptable practice.

For any other cases: **you should be really careful about doing that!** 
As this practice in that case means: violating [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

The point is: a class should only know about its direct neighbors. You don't want to write code like

```
myField.doSomething().inSomeOtherClass().andNow2HopsAway() ...
```

because that couples this code to a completely different class.

Long story short: don't build **fluent** APIs just for the fun of it. Consider carefully where they make sense; and never forget about the Law of Demeter!

EDIT; after reading your questions and comments more thoroughly; I think you not only confused yourself, but also us:

as of now

```
public RECT getPositionOfClient() { ... returns an instance of RECT }
```

And top, left, ... are **fields** on RECT.

So you get

```
int whatever = foo.getPositionOfClient().top;
```

Done. It is a field; you don't need anything else but use ".top" for example when your method is already returning a RECT!

Comment: If Mr. anonymous-downvote is still around; kindly explain what motivated your action.

Comment: i see your point, however wouldn't it be reasonable to do this fluently for getRect().getTop(); Instead of having 4 different methods that independently return top, bottom, right and left? - I've dropped you an upvote to even out the downvote. I appreciate your answer!

Comment: As said; it depends on your context. The big question is: what is a "good" return value for a method called getTop() - another RECT? Would that be the same one as getRect() gave you - or the one "on top" of the RECT from getRect()?!

Comment: Well, RECT now as it is has a call for the direct int types, and not getters. So that would basically just be getters for the ints. And not new RECTs.

Comment: I updated my answer; probably everybody just "over-complicated" things her. Hope my latest edit helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't call a method upon another method, you call a method on the *return value* of another method. `method().method().method();` is only legal code if `method()` returns a type that itself has a method names `method()`. For your code, you just need whatever type `getPositionOfTop()` returns to itself have `getTop()` and `getBottom()`.

Answer (score 0):

Methods are called of an object. The thing you call a method/property on, must be an object.
If you want to do method chaining, each method should return a value that is actually an object. (Except the last method).
Classes that are designed to be usable for method chaining just return themselves as the return value of a method.

Answer (score 0):

Its not like you call method() upon another method. For Ex:

You have  a json string which is Mapped to a Pojo class named Demo. So now you are usong a Gson Class library of gson api which is used to convert json string to Class Object.

```
new Gson().fromJson(inputString,Demo.class).toString().
```

So Here Gson() which is a constructor method return Object of Gson class.

```
new Gson()
```

Now we can call the fromJson(String, ClassofT) method using the object returned by Gson Constructor. This method convert the given json string to a Demo Class Object.

```
new Gson().fromJson(inputString,Demo.class)
```

Then we are calling the toString method of Demo class to print our information. So as you can see that you can call a method on a return type object and is valid if that method exists for that object.